How do I efficiently manage relationships in a multi-tenant application
I am developing a multi-tenant application that manages information about suppliers and clients, using Entity Framework for user logins and roles. Suppliers provide products to clients, and clients can report issues related to these products. Each supplier defines a list of acceptable issues that clients can report. For example, if a supplier delivers food to a client, the client can report that the food is expired. Additionally, suppliers can define specific issues for individual clients.
The schema I have now is as follows:

Entity framework tables like AspNetUsers table that handles the login, and AspNetRoles table that assigns roles such as supplier and client.
The Orders table where the supplier submits an order to a client. It contains the following columns:

SupplierId, referencing AspNetUsers table, with a check constraint to ensure it's a supplier.
ClientId, also referencing AspNetUsers table, with check constraint to ensure it's a client.
...


The Issues table includes:

SupplierId, with the same check constraint as above to ensure it's a supplier.
...


The IssueClient table which includes:

IssueId referencing issues table.
ClientId, with the same check constraint as above to ensure it's a client. I need this because a issue can be specific to a client.



My issue with the current schema is, I need to include SupplierId and ClientId in multiple tables, all of which is referencing a single column in AspNetUsers table. Every time I use those id's, I must verify that the supplier is indeed a supplier for the specific client, and vice versa. While I can verify it by checking in the Orders table, it doesn't seem correct.
If I change the schema to add a relationship table between supplier and clients and use that in the orders table. Will this help me? Is this unnecessary? I don't think it will even help with the Issues and IssueClient tables because in the issues table, I need the supplier id, and in the IssueClient table I need the client id. I'll still need to check that the supplier is associated with this client.
In summary, should I add a new table to manage relationships, is it unnecessary, or are both approaches correct?

If all the orders for a SupplierId, ClientId pair are deleted should the Issues (or whatever) for the pair persist? You should complete your model requirements first.

@Serg Thanks for the catch. Didn't think of it. So in my case, I will still need to keep the relationship even if it will only really help me in one table.
